# Adding a class into another class's return statement

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react, but I am wondering if there is a solution to creating a nesting class in the return statement of an existing class? Ive tried to look for other solution and had no choice but to ask this here.

Assuming in the return class in App.js:

```
import { useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import {  MapContainer } from "./maps";
import { GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

return (

      <div class="body">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="topnav">
            <input id="seachbar" name="seachbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." ref={inputRef} ></input>
            <button onclick="document.getElementByName('seachbar').name = ''" class='removeButton'>X</button>
            <button type="submit" class='searchButton'>Search</button>

        </div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div class="content">
          <MapContainer/>
        </div>
      </div>


 );
```

I had tried to add the class inside it but kept getting an error stating that export has to be outside the statement. Is there a function that I can use to nest it inside? Just adding more context I am trying to add in google maps into the div section but the google maps contain 2 different exports.

Assuming in the return class in maps.js:

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={
          {
            lat: 3.1474767381135407,
            lng: 101.69958884212062
          }
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDkXk3MuVjovvaVAnl2wt2j_2ES-INLJ0s'
})(MapContainer);
```

I want to use both the section of the export in order to generate a map from map.js into App.js. However when I call  in App.js after importing. It would say "loading map" but unable to do so.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're trying to do but yeah, just do `<SomeOtherComponent />` (not necessarily a _class_ per se, a component--could be a functional component) just like your pseudocode shows. Please share a [mcve] showing the actual code.

Comment: Ive added some details regarding the component info. Ive tried to add in the component but having issues calling it since the maps require both components in another file.